getting confused with making my own salesforce admin roadmap
I have gone through alot videos and refrences but confused to figure out which topics do i need to cover at very beginning stage of becoming salesforce administrator. In my case , am t a blank page with some basics about salesforce, crm, org, objects ,custom objects, n all. so could i get some elders advice to compensate my growth to be better me

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/trails/force_com_admin_beginner is a good start

Hi, Harsh, and welcome to SFSE! Please take a moment to read about [ask] and take our quick two minute [tour]. Please note that we have certain expectations of the content posted here. Notably, you don't need to show gratitude (that is implied), nor do you need to sign (the user name is already displayed on the post). Aside from that, we hope you enjoy your stay here.

There's lots of ways to get better at Salesforce. Consider going through the Admin Super Set on Trailhead. By completing this set, you'll be a very knowledgeable Admin. It looks like a lot of work, but it's actually broken down into units that are typically 10-20 minutes at a time, so you don't need to do it all at once. There's also individual topics on Trailhead, which you can filter by level of difficulty, product, and role, to help you focus on specific topics you might be interested in learning.
Also, you should know there's lot of different communities out there that are willing to help you. There's us, of course, as well as Groups, the Activity Feed, and more. Feel free to look around. There's a lot of ways to get the information you're looking for, and there's a lot of people you can ask for help.

N.B.  Better to start the SFDC admin journey in 2024 when the no-code, low-code toolset is so much more powerful than back in 2008 when I started

thanks a million
